# Duck won't quack: ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get animation to work in a small Angular app.

I got the animation-css working in a stand-alone app, basically just this.

```
<button value="val" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">cont</button>
<div ng-hide="toggle" class="fader"></div>
```

I got the CSS to make "fader" a little square that fades in-and-out.

But, when I put it in a (slightly) larger application, it just blinks in and out as if the animation CSS weren't there at all.

I do not understand the `performAnimation` code well enough to debug it directly, but
I have eliminated what I think are the two obvious possibilities:

- that the ngAnimate module was not loaded at all by the application.  No, the `enterClass` and `leaveClass` of angular-animate.js are called at (what seem to me to be) the appropriate times.
- that the CSS was somehow not loaded or overridden.  No, if I set the classes (like ng-hide-add and ng-hide-active) on the block by hand, it fades appropriately.

Any suggestions on how I might track this down?  (Angular 1.3.0-beta.17)

Answer (score 0):

Grrr.

The last thing I checked was the version of the code *that worked*.  Angular 1.3.0-beta.17.  Angular 1.2.14 animation does not work or works differently.

30 seconds after I posted this.

Comment: Yeah, AngularJS is changing fast and introduce a lot of breaking changes along the way. Becareful to look at the documentation with the same version of angular you are using.